# Spring boot example: Can't access restlet from browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried to build a very basic spring boot example based on this [spring-boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). Tests works as expected but I can't access the restlet via http://localhost/ei-bacon/test because it will return a HTTP 404 error.

HelloController.java:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Ei Bacon welcomes you!";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Ei Bacon welcomes you again!";
    }
}
```

There may be a clash with the index file (/index.html) and the first request mapping. But the second one (/test) should work but doesn't. Do I enter the wrong url?

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/ei-bacon"/>
```

Application.java:

```
package ch.ffhs.innt.eibacon.hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run your application as standalone Spring Boot application and don't deploy it into an application server, the correct url would be `http://localhost:8080/test` or `http://localhost:8080/`, as shown in the guide.

If you want to deploy it as WAR file in an application server or standalone Tomcat, your main class has to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and implement the method `configure(SpringApplicationBuilder)`, as shown in the manual here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: I deployed it on a local Tomcat Server on Port 80 and a remote Tomcat server running on Port 8080. I also have a index.html which will be displayed correctly at the respective port. Except my Restlet as wrote above. I guess the restlet and the html file should be accessable under the same context and port?

Comment: If you want do deploy it to a standalone tomcat, then you used the wrong guide (as you can see, e.g. the guide doesn't have <packaging>war</packaging> in the pom file). It's only intended to be packaged as JAR and run standalone. For WAR deployment, use https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/ and http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: But if I make a clean install which deletes the target folder, the build process generates a new war file which I deploy to the server and there's no jar.

Comment: Yes, that's ok if you do what's needed for a WAR deployment I.e. you have to create a class which implements the SpringBootServletInitializer, as described in my links

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you so much! :-D 
Why does Spring generate a unusable war for standalone deployment?

PS, If u post it as answer I can mark it as the answer ;-)

Comment: Because you told Maven to create it like that